# CKeditor и изменение кода (замена угловых скобок, кавычек и т.д.)

Tags: ckeditor

Добрый день!

Дано: CKEditor 4.1.2

При вставке кода типа: `<code  class="code">&lt;meta content=&quot;IE=edge&quot; http-equiv=&quot;X-UA-Compatible&quot;&gt;</code>`

Редактор либо убирает тег code вообще, а скобки и кавычки в теге meta превращает в знаки и тег становится тегом.

Дописала в конфиг:

```
// разрешить теги <code>
    CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push(/<(code)[^>]*>.*<\/code>/ig);
```

Тогда code остается на месте, но в его содержимом все равно изменяются кавычки и скобки. 
При этом стоит: `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true; //ACF disable=true`

Что дописать, чтобы код оставался в том виде, в котором его ввели в редактор.

А и еще при этом содержимое тега code пропадает в визуальном представлении, что тоже не комильфо.